# Function ereg_replace() is deprecated - How to clear this bug?

Tags: php, deprecated, ereg

I have written following PHP code:

```
$input="menu=1&type=0&";

print $input."<hr>".ereg_replace('/&/', ':::', $input);
```

After running above code, it gives following warning,

> Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated

How can I resolve this warning.

Comment: A Reference Question is: [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6270004/367456)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Switch to [`preg_replace`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_replace) and update the expression to use preg syntax (PCRE) instead of ereg syntax (POSIX) [where there are differences<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.posix) (just as it says to do in the manual for [`ereg_replace`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/ereg_replace)).

Answer (score 35):

```
print $input."<hr>".ereg_replace('/&/', ':::', $input);
```

becomes

```
print $input."<hr>".preg_replace('/&/', ':::', $input);
```

More example :

```
$mytext = ereg_replace('[^A-Za-z0-9_]', '', $mytext );
```

is changed to

```
$mytext = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/', '', $mytext );
```

Answer (score 6):

change the call to ereg_replace to use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/ereg_replace says:

> Note: As of PHP 5.3.0, the regex extension is deprecated in favor of the [PCRE extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

Thus, [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) is in every way better choice. Note there are some differences in pattern syntax though.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC they suggest using the `preg_` functions instead (in this case, `preg_replace`).

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php#98602) is more information regarding replacing ereg_replace with preg_replace