# youtube api search.php foreach loop error

Tags: php, api, youtube, feed

My [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) search result fetch php script. Is displaying errors:

**SEARCH.php**

```html
<?php
 $ytapi="http://gdata.youtube.com";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html 
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
<meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Searching for videos by keyword - Muftatube</title>
    <style>
 p{font-size: 30px;color: #FFE131; font-weight: bold;}
    td {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    td.line {
      border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    }a{color: #ff0000; font-weight:bold; text-size: 18px;}
a:hover {
background-color: yellow;
 }</style>
  </head>
  <body
<form action="search.php" method="get">
      Search: 
      <input type="text" name="vq" /> 
      Items per page: 
      <select name="i">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form></div>
<div id="nav">
</div>

<div id="section" text-align="center">

    <?php
    // if form not submitted
    // display search box
    if (!isset($_GET['vq'])) {

echo "<h2>Welcome to FullMufta Tube</h2><br /> This Is Search Page Go to home To serch and browse Videos";
    // if form submitted
    } else {
      // check for search keywords
      // trim whitespace
      // encode search string
      if (!isset($_GET['vq']) || empty($_GET['vq'])) {
        die ('ERROR: Please enter one or more search keywords');
      } else {
        $vqs = $_GET['vq'];
        $vq = ereg_replace('[[:space:]]+', ' ', trim($vqs));
        $vq = urlencode($vq);
      }

      // set max results per page
      if (!isset($_GET['i']) || empty($_GET['i'])) {
        $i = 10;
      } else {
        $i = htmlentities($_GET['i']);
        if($i>100)exit;
      }
      // set start index
      if (!isset($_GET['pageID']) || $_GET['pageID'] <= 0) {
        $o = 1;
      } else {
        $pageID = htmlentities($_GET['pageID']);
        $o = (($pageID-1) * $i)+1;
      }

      // generate feed URL
      $feedURL = $ytapi."/feeds/api/videos?vq={$vq}&max-results={$i}&start-index={$o}";

      // read feed into SimpleXML object
      $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
        echo '<!-- $feedURL: '.$feedURL.' -->';
      ?>

      <h1>Search results: </h1><h4><?php echo $vqs; ?></h4>
<table>
      <?php
      // iterate over entries in resultset
      // print each entry's details
      foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
        // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
        $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

        // get video player URL
        $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
        $watch = $attrs['url'];

        // get <yt:duration> node for video length
        $yt = $media->children($ytapi.'/schemas/2007');
        $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
        $length = $attrs['seconds'];

        // get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
        $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
        if ($gd->rating) {
          $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
          $rating = $attrs['average'];
        } else {
          $rating = 0;
        }

        // get video ID
        $arr = explode('/',$entry->id);
        $id = $arr[count($arr)-1];

        // print record
        preg_match('#v\=(.*?)\&#',$watch,$vid);
        $watch='watch/?vid='.$vid[1];
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\" class=\"line\"></td></tr>\n";
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td><a href=\"{$watch}\">
        <img src=\"fullmuftaimg.php?vid=$vid[1]&sz=0\"/></a></td>\n";
        echo "<td><a href=\"{$watch}\">
        {$media->group->title}</a><br/>\n";
        echo sprintf("%0.2f", $length/60) . " min. | {$rating} user rating |
        {$viewCount} views<br/>\n";
        echo $media->group->description . "<br/>\n";
        echo "</td></tr>\n";
      }
    }
    ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

It was working before but now its not working.  I changed the server and run it again but the search results do not appear.

**Error message**

> Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in
>   /home/u691059747/public_html/search.php on line 69 Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file():
>   http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=dj&max-results=10&start-index=1:1:
>   parser error : Document is empty in
>   /home/u691059747/public_html/search.php on line 92 Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(): in /home/u691059747/public_html/search.php on
>   line 92 Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in
>   /home/u691059747/public_html/search.php on line 92 Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file():
>   http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=dj&max-results=10&start-index=1:1:
>   parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in
>   /home/u691059747/public_html/search.php on line 92 Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(): in /home/u691059747/public_html/search.php on
>   line 92 Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in
>   /home/u691059747/public_html/search.php on line 92

Search results:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/u691059747/public_html/search.php on line 101

Comment: check once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132844/function-ereg-replace-is-deprecated-how-to-clear-this-bug

Comment: next time, don't use `.......` and `!!!` in your question.

Comment: Adding a link and trying to fix the grammar and spelling issues.

Comment: @Ofir Baruch ok sir i will care this issue

Comment: Dear experts , basically i want to get output from youtube api rss  because youtube is banned in pakistan so i get this code from github but now this is not working this show too much errors i am not a professional i am a kid :)

Comment: plz give me ans dear experts i am waiting

Answer (score 0):

Just note that YouTube has disabled fetching information using their API v2 and you should switch to version 3.

But in any case, when I print the `$feedURL` variable in your `search.php` I receive i.e:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=dj&max-results=10&start-index=1
```

Browsing this URL gives output of:

```
No longer available
```

So you should first try to figure out why this youtube URL no longer works ( if not V2/3 thing then maybe parameter names has changed / etc ... )

And since the string above is just a text - not a valid XML string, you get the PHP error:

```
 parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in
```